# How can I make "element wise" comparsion inside of the tf.function?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I try to make my own activation function in TensorFlow 2 and the function looks like this:

```
@tf.function
def f(x):
  r = 2
  if x>=0:
    return (r**2 * x + 1)**(1/r) - 1/r
  else:
    return K.exp(r*x) - 1/r
```

The problem is that it cant take as argument `tf.constant([2.0, 3.0])`because there is an issue with conditions. I have tried `tf.math.qreater_equal(x, 0)` which lead to same output also `tf.cond()`. I have had no luck with documentation examples either.
It returns error:

```
InvalidArgumentError:  The second input must be a scalar, but it has shape [2]
     [[{{node cond/switch_pred/_2}}]] [Op:__inference_f_7469065]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if` statements are converted to `cond`, but that only takes scalar arguments for the predicate (and does no broadcasting).  Try [`where`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where) instead:

```
return tf.where(x >= 0, (r**2 * x + 1)**(1/r) - 1/r, K.exp(r*x) - 1/r))
```

(Can't test this currently with TensorFlow, but that's at least how Numpy behaves...)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I cant believe that I havent tried that

Comment: It does however eagerly evaluate both cases. So you might gain something by factoring out repeated evaluations when possible.